# Cannot find the gensupport "google.golang.org/api/gensupport" in golang project with version of "google.golang.org/api"=>v0.103.0

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, go-modules

previously I was using

> "google.golang.org/api"=>v0.10.0

in my go.mod file and I was able to import

> gensupport "google.golang.org/api/gensupport"

But with new

> "google.golang.org/api"=>v0.103.0

I was unable to import gensupport and as I and my colleague have investigated, gensupport was shifted to

> "google.golang.org/api/internal/gensupport"

but while using this import there is one error saying

> Use of the internal package is not allowed

So now how I will be able to use gensupport with new "google.golang.org/api"=>v0.103.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to vendor an older version of the library.
This package has been marked for internal use for a long time and was also marked to allow for breakages. See https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/416 for options.